# What's the difference between these two key type argument declarations?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics, keyof

When using a generic wrapper around some kind of known state, I ran into incompatible type errors when casting a child to its parent. The idea being that if `Tomato` extends `Fruit`, then `Wrapper<Tomato>` as `Wrapper<Fruit>` ought to work.

```js
interface Wrapper<TProps> {
    // This next line is correct
    mergeWith<K extends keyof TProps>(merger: (key: K) => any): void;

    update<K extends keyof TProps>(updater: (value: TProps[K]) => any): void;
}

interface BrokenWrapper<TProps> {
    // Somehow this next line seems identical to mergeWith above
    mergeWith(merger: (key: keyof TProps) => any): void;

    update<K extends keyof TProps>(updater: (value: TProps[K]) => any): void;
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQJYDsAusBOAzSBjW1QB3ACw3gHsl5YAPNJAEwJVNHJYwChk0td4AYugCuCFAAZQAb06g5oOLCYAuUEmEBbAEYYA3JwC+3VBmx5QAFXIbIKcpNr0moIaInTZ8nOQA25dKoAROhKgfpGxrxm8ADq6JAADgkYADwWAAro5AnQAHwe8qAglsQIBFR0oD7I8GWg3ughOCiechoYAOawMWLEKQDSoI6wjAQA1rAAnuSYlpnZeQAU7ehdAaCLE5Oq-QCUoAC8+ZBIk7uqAG7kCAz6raDCCQy2sANDdCPOWzNzWTm5i0ez14qkWF0gPmEsFUGT+0AA2v0ALr7I6gE5nS7XW6GTiRUz8CBZCZIOKJZLoNLzf4FeTFADK1lgxHIhFALDqFRQVRqClgsA0BBuIxQCBwEPZ5FAABkAIyy9FacgXeBaYTcurIBpNFAAOn19xWXR6LGWnQwoK2qm+s1hC1Rx1O51AVxud0KxQAktziDAFEyOUgOpLQAwpYReuikOxSOhQO0WOQGOifNApShJslkxGWOjQF0qOgxfcgS83sNRqAbb8FgDSyCNuDIdCazlESjDo7MS7seE8cULKUCIR-GNoJwM8kXCIxIdQGSkqlXGJxLl9JP4FYbHY5wuKWlrLZ7GvON4kNBuVuj3PAoF0QRhEgxtHCEh75ZD3Z9GeL-UYNyDg-bcpT9ZcUDuAchyGRp-AIWx2VYJUUDsDQJ0zeBwGJEYwLnTDyBJPclxnCQTw3Il8JGK8d0AvCCPiRdKSo49v0oX9aMoz8pUA2930fZ9WTfP12KQJiWPPblxQvABRGC4xorCRM499hLAu5OCAA)

Comment: This is ultimately going to be a [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) and [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) issue. I should be able to call `brokenFruit.mergeWith((x: "seeds")=>0)`, where the callback *requires* its parameter be the string literal `"seeds"`. But a value `brokenTomato.mergeWith((x: "seeds")=>0)` is an error; its callback must accept either a `"seeds"` or a `"color"` argument. Since I can't use `brokenTomato` in place of `brokenFruit`, it means `BrokenTomato` is not a `BrokenFruit`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting jcalz. I appreciate you naming the category of problem. Regarding the difference between the error code and non-error code, should my conclusion be that using `mergeWith<K extends keyof TProps>(merger: (key: K)` constrains `key` to be anything that could be a key of TProps (eg. just `"seeds"`) but writing `(key: keyof TProps)` requires it to be exactly `keyof TProps`? ie. `"seeds" | "color"`

Comment: The generic one is more forgiving in what type of callback it accepts, but it becomes much harder to implement. (After all, what can you do with a callback `merger` of type `(k: K)=>void` for some type `K` that you don't know?  Pretty much nothing.   You can't call `merger("seeds")` because maybe `merger` only accepts `"color"`.  The concrete one is less forgiving in what it accepts: it needs to be a callback that can both handle `"seeds"` and `"color"` as an input.  This is much easier to implement.  Frankly I think the problem is with your non-"broken" interface.

Comment: Note that in general just because `Y extends X` it doesn't mean that `F<Y> extends F<X>`.  If you plan to have `F<T>` both read and write values of type `T`, then `F<Y>` and `F<X>` are generally unrelated; you can't substitute one for the other at all.  So "if `Tomato` extends `Fruit`, then `Wrapper<Tomato>` as `Wrapper<Fruit>` ought to work" will only be true or safe in very specific circumstances.  TypeScript does normally allow a lack of safety in a bunch of places, though, so you might still force this relation even if it's unsafe, depending on the use case.

Comment: "Frankly I think the problem is with your non-"broken" interface." Hmm, I see what you mean here. This makes a lot more sense after reading more about [covariance vs contravariance](https://medium.com/@michalskoczylas/covariance-contravariance-and-a-little-bit-of-typescript-2e61f41f6f68). Thanks again for your help!